# Drop shadows around svg/vml or canvas shapes

Tags: html, canvas, css, svg, vml

Is it easy to create drop shadows under shapes created with svg (vml for IE7/8 compatibility) or under shapes created with html5's canvas?  I'm looking to create an arrow with a drop shadow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an [svg example](http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/svg/filters/arrow-with-dropshadow.svg) showing how to get a dropshadow:

```
  <defs>
    <filter id="dropshadow" height="130%">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="3"/> 
      <feOffset dx="2" dy="2" result="offsetblur"/> 
      <feMerge> 
        <feMergeNode/>
        <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/> 
      </feMerge>
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <polygon points="58.263,0.056 100,41.85 58.263,83.641 30.662,83.641 62.438,51.866 0,51.866 0,31.611 62.213,31.611 30.605,0 58.263,0.056" fill="#EEEEEE" filter="url(#dropshadow)"/>
```

The important bits are:

1. The `<filter>` definition ([svg filters](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/filters.html) can do a lot more than just dropshadows)
2. To use the filter, reference it by the `url(#id)` syntax filter via the CSS 'filter' property, or presentation attribute as in the example above